# How to get response from static library in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnectiondelegate

In my application I am using one static library. In that library I implemented code for establish a connection with the server. For server interaction I used `NSURLSession` but it's delaying the UI response to avoid it I have started using `NSURLConnection` delegate methods now I am getting the response from server but here I don't know how to send the response back to actual code from did finish loading method.

In my team I want to distribute this library to both iphone and ipad development engineers. They don't have any control on server related code everything I implemented in static library. So please show me the solution for my problem thanks in advance.

The below is the code which I used in one class of static library:

StaticClass:

.h File

```
@interface StaticClass : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate>

{
NSMutableDictionary  *responseDictionary;
NSUserDefaults *serviceURlInUserDefaults;
NSData *responseData;

}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DataReciverDelegate>delegate;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSData *responseData;


-(void)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)name password:(NSString*)password serviceUrl:(NSString*)serviceUrl domainName:(NSString*)domainName ;


@end
```

## import "StaticClass.h"

```
@protocol DataReciverDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)responseDictionary:(NSDictionary *)response;

@end


@implementation StaticClass
@synthesize responseData;


-(void)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)name password:(NSString*)password serviceUrl:(NSString*)serviceUrl domainName:(NSString*)domainName 
{

 NSString *ApiStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@“http://login.com”];

    NSURL *Url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[loginApiStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   NSURLRequest *ApiRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loginUrl];

    NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:ApiRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    self.responseData=data;

}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    responseDictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:0 error:nil];

    [_delegate responseDictionary:responseDictionary];

}

@end
```

Response where I want to use is in class1 :

Here please let me know how can i include that delegate which i created in static library class

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLSessionDelegate>

{

}

@end

@implementation Class1


-(void)login
{
StaticClass *object1=[[StaticClass alloc]init];

[object loginWithUsername:@“AAA” password:@“BBB” serviceUrl:url domainName:dname];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either offer API to notify that response has been read from the connection, or you can send a notification.

The first can be accomplished by either implementing a delegate protocol and setting the delegate in the using app, or by using block-based API, where the using app would set a block to handle events. You see these two patterns very often in system-provided API, including `NSUrlConnection`.

Another option is to use notifications. You register for a particular notification name in the using app, and in the lib you post once your connection returns data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a protocol in your static library like:

```
@protocol DataReciverDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)dataReceived:(NSData *)data;

@end
```

Also declare a property there like:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <DataReciverDelegate>delegate;
```

In your static library implementation, implement the `connectionDidFinishLoading` like:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
   [_delegate dataReceived:_dataYouReceived];
}
```

Now you need to implement the `DataReciverDelegate` in the class you need to get the data, and When you create the object of your static library class, set the delegate.

Comment: Hi Midhun thanks for your reply. You are telling that implementation of DataReciverDelegate in the class you need to get the data means I have to redefined in class how i defined in static library right? And one more thing is I have to implement delegate method in class. Next how can i set delegate for library object in class please let me know.

Comment: @Naresh: You need to implement the DataReceiverDelegate in the class you need to get the data. When you create the object of static library class set the delegate to self

Comment: Hi midhun really thanks a lot for your support. I am little bit confuse in setting delegate can you tell me where can i set delegate. I had edited my question with sample code. Can you please through the code and let me know the place.

Comment: Set it after `StaticClass *object1=[[StaticClass alloc]init];` like object1.delegate = self; and implement the dataReceived` method in `Class1`